# Why this coffeescript does not run?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

coffee test.coffee with this code

```
###
#/usr/local/bin/coffee $0
###
console.log 'test'
```

prints

```
Running node v0.11.13
/home/user/tst/test.coffee:3
 */usr/local/bin/coffee $0
                        ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
```

but with this code

```
###
#usr/local/bin/coffee $0
###
console.log 'test'
```

it runs ok

```
Running node v0.11.13
test
```

my coffee binary is located at /usr/local/bin/coffee but I expected this string to be not involved as this is a comment. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code [compiles to the following JS code](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%23%23%23%0A%23%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fcoffee%20%240%0A%23%23%23%0Aconsole.log%20'test'):

```js
/*
 */usr/local/bin/coffee $0
 */
console.log('test');
```

Because Coffee compiles you block comment into its JS equivalent, replacing

```coffee
###
# block
# comment
###
```

with its idiomatic JS version

```js
/*
 * block
 * comment
 */
```

But since your comment starts with `/`, it compiles to invalid JS.

To fix this problem simply add whitespace between `#` and `/`:

```coffee
###
# /usr/local/bin/coffee $0
###
console.log 'test'
```

**P.S.:** I [created an issue on CoffeeScript issue tracker](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3638) based on your question.